# Inheritance in table creation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create **Worker** and **Student** tables which contains a lot of similar information (First name, second name etc.), so I'm going to extract another like abstract table named **Person**, which will contain general information for **Worker** and **Student** tables.

Which is the best way to do that?

Also I need that ids will be unique i.e. there isn't the same id in **Worker** table and **Student** table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table `persons` with all the combined information and a `person_id`.

Create two additional tables, `workers` and `students`.  The primary keys for these tables are foreign keys to the `persons` table:

```
create table students (
    student_id int primary key references persons (person_id),
    . . .
);

create table workers (
    worker_id int primary key references persons (person_id),
    . . .
);
```